# how to match keywords with best description

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I have 50 rows in mysql. Each row consists of a number of keywords that are comma separated. I have another table with consists of some description. I want to loop over all the descriptions and want to find out which row of keywords are the best match for that description. how can i accomplish this. I am using PHP and Mysql. I am using sphinx too. But not much luck there.
Are there any other ways to that?

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just do it conventionally. Loop though all the keywords lists, and find which document(s) they match. Store that list somewhere, and then can look though it to get the inverse list directly.

Otherwise you are looking at a variation of Prospective Search (mentioning the name, so can use it look for further reading material!)

Which sphinx can do. Build an index on the keywords table. Then loop though each description and build a query - using 'quorum' syntax. So the query only needs to match one (or more) of the words.

For each document, sphinx will return you a list of possible keyword matches in relevence order. Can just take the top document as the 'best match'

The key thing is not to take all the keyword documents returned from sphinx, as it will include many very low quality matches. Basically need to post process the results, and discard the tail end of the results.

Using SPH_RANK_MATCHANY is a good ranking calculation for this.